# Application transfer from internal memory to SD card in Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd

How to move applications from internal memory of Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 to SD card without adding any applications?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Your question is quite generic. What have you tried? Where's the issue? You might wish to start by reading our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), which sums up some background and hints.

Comment: I suggest you to check about Custom-ROM available for you phone, for better UI and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Format the SD card as ext2. Move folders to the SD card with a file manager. Make symlinks in the original location so that the OS can still see the files there. Would be easier to let an app do this for you...

*Edit* yes you will definitely need root access to do this.

I have done it using apps aparted and link2sd.

I think the OP should give more info about why the use of apps is unacceptable, because it does make life more difficult. In fact, if OP does not already have a terminal Emulator installed, then I think it will only be possible at all if OP can get shell access through adb shell.

Comment: Need to root first. and could you please describe your answer?